# _document.js en next.js no hace nada

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

estoy empezando un proyecto on next.js y recien estoy configurando el entorno y me encuentro con el siguiente problema:

```
import Document, { Head, Main, NextScript } from 'next/document'

export default class extends Document {
  render() {
    /**
    * Here we use _document.js to add a "lang" propery to the HTML object if
    * one is set on the page.
    **/
    return (
      <html lang={this.props.__NEXT_DATA__.props.pageProps.lang || 'en'}>
        <Head>
            <title>inicio</title>
        </Head>
        <body>
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </html>
    )
  }
}
```

el problema es que este archivo `_document.js` que obviamente se encuentra en la carpeta page del proyecto, no esta teniendo efecto alguno, el titulo se muestra como localhost y el lenguaje del html no se define, ayuda

Comment: Te falta ser mas especifico, aparentemente estas usando `react` pero tu no haz especificado que estas usando `react`, ademas veo algunos errores en el codigo tambien y mas informacion faltante, por favor asegurate de colocar todas las tecnologias que estas usando y editar la pregunta para poner todo lo que sea relevante.

Comment: como aclare en la pregunta, recién empiezo con el proyecto y el archivo lo acababa de crear y empecé a testear si los cambios hacían efecto, en la documentación de `next.js` hay una parte especifica que habla sobre el archivo `_app.js` donde cito: `Si su aplicación se está ejecutando y acaba de agregar una personalizada App, deberá reiniciar el servidor de desarrollo. Solo se requiere si pages/_app.js no existía antes.`, algo que se describe por si solo, pero en mi caso me paso con el archivo `_document.js` tuve que reiniciar el servidor para que `next` pueda leer dicho archivo

Comment: Ese no es el punto, el punto es que no sabemos que tecnologias estas usando, tu acabas de mencionar `next.js`. pero tu codigo parece `react` hay que ser mas especificos, no podemos ayudarte si no sabemos que tecnologia estas usando, eso no es javascript puro, ahora, esa cita que haces y esa aclaracion que dices no estan en la pregunta, esta informacion es nueva, no nos estas mencionando nada mas alla de lo que dijiste en tu comentario, porfavor edita la pregunta y pon las tecnologias usadas, yo en lo personal no puedo ayudarte ya que no se sobre `react` pero

Comment: Otras personas que saben sobre `react` podran ayudarte y veran tu pregunta si haces un buen uso de las etiquetas, por eso es tan importante que pongas todas las etiquetas necesarias, pues estas ayudan a que la pregunta no solo reciba mas atencion si no que ademas sea respondida de manera mas rapida, por lo que veo eso que estas usando `next.js` es bastante parecido a react, (si es que no es react), te recomendaria mejor usar react, es mas conocido y su comunidad es enorme.

Comment: entiendo lo que dices, uso mucho stackOverflow, pregunto y ayudo, entiendo perfectamente a lo que vas, no puedo hacer un buen uso de etiquetas, si conoces react, sabrás que next.js es un pequeño framework que hace server-rendering de aplicaciones basadas en JavaScript usando algo similar a react, la etiqueta next.js no aparece aqui, por lo tanto opte por usar la etiqueta javascript

Comment: si usas, next.js y sabes sobre react, el archivo `_document.js` se podria decir que es fundamental en dicho framework, se usa comúnmente para aumentar las etiquetas `<html>` y de su aplicación `<body>`. Esto es necesario porque las páginas de Next.js omiten la definición del marcado del documento circundante, lo entenderias de solo leer el titulo pero claro, no sabes de react ni mucho menos de next.js

Comment: Ohhh... es cierto, ahora que lo recuerdo no puedes referenciar una etiqueta que no existe si no apartir de ciertos puntos, lo habia olvidado, ummmm si es una light-weight version de react (resumiendolo) yo te aconsejaria que igual pusieras la etiqueta `react`, pues el parentezco entre `next.js` y react es increible!, creo que acudirian mas personas a investigar que es `next.js` y el porque tu codigo no hace lo que requieres siendo tan parecidos ambas tecnologias. igual mirare si puedo editar tu pregunta para poner la etiqueta `next.js`.

Answer (score 0):

La etiqueta html la debes importar desde 'next/document', quedando de la siguiente manera:

```
import Document, { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from 'next/document'
```